# Disable Sortable For Single Element at Runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using JQuery UI Sortable is it possible to turn off/disable sorting/dragging on one `li`at runtime?

So to be clear; at page load all `li` elements are sortable. I click a button and the first `li` element is now not sortable/draggable.

I have tried the method following method but this doesn't disable/turn it off at runtime:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#slide-list").sortable({ items: '> li:not(.fixed)' });

    $('#lock-slide-btn').click(function() {

        $("#slide-list li").first().addClass('fixed');

        // The above li is still draggable and sortable.
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Accroding to the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-destroy) you should use the `destroy` method in order to remove sorting capabilities from an element

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#slide-list").sortable({ items: '> li:not(.fixed)' });

    $('#lock-slide-btn').click(function() {

        $("#slide-list li").first().sortable('destroy');

    })
});
```